# Always true when testing if string == various OR'ed alternatives

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

So the problem I am currently having is that my program always calls the 'md5cypher' class which I have defined, even if the input is not in that list:

```
def enc():
    global toe
    if toe=='md5' or 'M' or 'm' or 'Md5' or 'MD5':
        print("Md5 Encryption Cypher")
        md5cypher()
    else:
        print("Sha1 Encryption Cypher")
        shacypher()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In reality you're checking:

```
if (toe=='md5') or 'M' or 'm' or....
```

And since `bool('M')` is `True`, you will always succeed that check. Try this instead:

```
if toe.lower() in ('md5', 'm'):
```

Comment: The latter is not an exact equivalent, as it will allow `mD5' also.

Answer (score 3):

`if toe=='md5' or 'M' or 'm' or 'Md5' or 'MD5':`

will always be evaluated to

`if toe=='md5' or True or True  or True  or True :`

What you want is:

```
if toe in ('md5', 'M', 'm', 'Md5', 'MD5'):
    print("Md5 Encryption Cypher")
    md5cypher()
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Literally, what you want to do is:

```
if toe=='md5' or toe=='M' or toe=='m' or toe=='Md5' or toe=='MD5'
```

- each part of the composite condition should be a standalone condition.

But in Python you can do it in a more elegant way, as indicated in other answers:

```
if toe in ('md5', 'M', 'm', 'Md5', 'MD5')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because checking a character will always return `True` therefore ensuring the if statement will execute.

Comment: I don't quite understand; How should I fix this then?

Comment: As pointed out above `if toe in ('md5', 'M', 'm', 'Md5', 'MD5')` should check if toe is any of those values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how boolean operators work in python.

You have to consider the operator precedences, and then your condition becomes

```
if (toe=='md5') or ('M') or ('m') or ('Md5') or ('MD5'):
```

which is equivalent to

```
if (toe=='md5') or True:
```

which of course is *always* true. A solution to your problem would be

```
if toe.lower() in ('m', 'md5'):
```

Comment: Will work incorrectly when `toe` is `'mD5'` (at least differently to what was specified in the OP) :-)

Comment: You sure? Why won’t the lower affect it?

Comment: It will, and that's the problem - there is no `'mD5'` in the list specified by the OP.

Comment: I'm quite convinced that this is an oversight of the OP, but 6 years later I wonder how relevant this discussion is.

Comment: As long as this thread is visible in search results, even if 20 years later, it should be helpful to other users. SO is not about answering a single user - it's about creating a knowledge base. So accuracy of an answer is actually very relevant. Perhaps it's an oversight - maybe you want to try to clear this out with the OP. As it stands, your proposed solution is not equivalent to what's requested in the question.

Comment: Given that the OP explicitly stated that the highest voted answer that literally contains the same code as mine solves his or her problem, I maintain my answer as is.

Comment: The highest voted answer is also invalid in this aspect :-) And, as I've mentioned - helping the OP directly is one result, but the more important outcome is helping all future readers :)

Comment: We will have to agree to disagree here. If somebody wants to hang themselves, you are the guy providing them with a good, sturdy rope. I'm the guy trying to talk them out of it. Both are valid reactions to this situation. I'm 100% convinced that mD5 supposed not mean to hash with SHA. So - again - I maintain my solution.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But noting this discrepancy explicitly in the answer doesn't hurt for sure as well. Thanks for your time, cheers! :-)